# Error with tor in ubuntu14.04

Tags: tor

I get obfs2 and obfs3 from tor. And i add it to torrc. But when i restart tor this error shown to me:

```
Checking if tor configuration is valid 
Apr 11 13:26:52.409 [notice] Tor v0.2.6.5-rc (git-c2f9c8df2d3c4981) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1f and Zlib 1.2.8. 
Apr 11 13:26:52.409 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning 
Apr 11 13:26:52.409 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc". 
Apr 11 13:26:52.409 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc". 
Apr 11 13:26:52.413 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'obfs2'. Failing. 
Apr 11 13:26:52.413 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above
```

**EDIT**

And here is the torrc file:

```
UseBridges 1
obfs2 **.***.***.***:*****
obfs2 ***.**.**.***:****
obfs2 ***.**.**.**:*****
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2 exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy --managed
```

Comment: Could you anonymize and add the contents of your `tor` config file (`/etc/tor/rc`)?

Comment: See the updated post.

Comment: tor not working for me in this way in Iran. I prefer downloading tor from official website and add bridges and running it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tor says that your config is invalid because of the unknown option 'obfs2':

```
Apr 11 13:26:52.413 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'obfs2'. Failing.
```

This is because there is no 'obfs2' client option for tor. The [correct syntax](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) would be `Bridge [transport] IP:ORPort [fingerprint]`, so your `torrc` should look like this:

```
UseBridges 1
Bridge obfs2 **.***.***.***:*****
Bridge obfs2 ***.**.**.***:****
Bridge obfs2 ***.**.**.**:*****
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2 exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy --managed
```

Comment: Remark: Instead of using obfs2,  you should use obfs3 or obfs4. Obfs2 has some issues. The other protocols offer an improvement.

Comment: Yup. I use obfs3 now. So faster and stable. Thanks.